# Add directive from directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a directive deciding if an input must be required, masked, etc... I ran into a situation that I need to add a new directive to it: basically this new directive adds the mask feature to the input.

```
<input type="text" formInput [rules]="rules"  [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

This is the formInput directive:

```
export class DefaultFormInputDirective {

@Input() private rules;
private el: ElementRef;

constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.defineRules();
}

defineRules() {

    if(this.rules == undefined) {
        return;
    }

    if(this.rules.indexOf('required') != -1) {
        this.el.nativeElement.required = true;
    }

    if(this.rules.indexOf('numeric') != -1) {
        // Here is where I need to add currencyMask directive
    }

}

}
```

This is the package I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases I would recommend to add attributes directly to the input as it seem much more approrpriate approach to me.

Anyway to achieve this you can create some kind of input abstraction component that will accept such inputs like `type`, will work with `ngModel` (you can find more about this [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html) or [here](https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73) for instance) and will contain whatever input you need with any attributes and directives.

So it may look like this in the end:

`<custom-input type="text" formInput [rules]="rules"  [(ngModel)]="value"></custom-input>`

Then you can hide your logic on what actual input has to be like in this component: assign needed attributes, directives and many other things you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

Adding directives dynamically is not supported. You can only add/remove components dynamically.